# JavaScript adding methods to objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, prototype, extends

I'm trying to extend a jQuery object but having some difficulty doing so.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.single-item').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 500,
        customPaging: function(slider, i) {
            // Theres a lot of stuff in this, removed for brevity
        },
        progressBar: function(slider, i) {
            // Want to create this method
            // alert is not defined
            window.onload(window.alert("YES"));
        }
    });
    // slick is not defined
    console.log(typeof(slick));
});
```

I'm trying a lot of things such as using jQuery's "extend":

```
var progressBar = function(slider, i) {
    window.onload(window.alert("YES"));
};
$.extend(slick, progressBar);
// Also tried '.slick-slider' in place of slick
```

Also tried implementing:

```
$.fn.progressBar = function(i) { 
    window.onload(alert(this.i))
};

$('.single-item').progressBar(i);
```

"customPaging" exists in the main js file, which I do not want to alter -- but rather extend additional methods to the object. It takes "slider" and "i" as parameters. Since it already exists in the main js file, it was easy enough to manipulate it.

However, I want to create an entirely new method called "progressBar" that also has access to the object's "slider" and "i" variables.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on and demonstrate how to create the method "progressBar" like I want?

Comment: `slick` is not defined because it's at `$.fn.slick`. As for the rest, show us how exactly you're "extending" this ?

Comment: I tried using jQuery's "extend" method like shown above, and also "Object.prototype.extend" but I'm not doing it properly, mostly because I don't know which is the Object I'm trying to extend. Do you have any advice?

Comment: You see, when you call `slick` you call it like `$(element).slick(options)`, the options are defined inside the plugin, there's no standardized way to extend those options.

Comment: so there isn't a way to write a new method called "progressBar" that has access to the "slide" and "i" variables contained in the object?

Comment: It isn't really a method on the plugin, it's a method on the option object passed in, and the plugin has to look for that method and do something with it, you can't extend the plugin that way unless the plugin itself has some built in way to extend the options, and they generally don't

Comment: I'm open to any alternative suggestions you may have, I only want to create a progress bar at the top of my slider that's tied to the page number of the slider (the "i" variable). Perhaps by modifying a different method that's been defined?

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because you adding method to configuration object of some plugin, not extending jquery element. If you want to add new method to the plugin you will probably have to edit its code.

Comment: I'd rather not change the source code because a bower update will overwrite any changes I make. Rather, I'd like to extend the object's functionality in a separate js file.